# C# run a vbscript encoded file without the .vbe extension using process start

Tags: c#, vbscript, encode

I can use process start and run a standard vbscript without its .vbs extension (see my code below) but how do you run a vbscript file that has been encoded using the VBScript Encoder object without the .vbe extension?

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"wscript.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "//e:vbscript noExtensionFile";
process.Start();
```

Comment: What error does it give to you? Don't you have permission to rename the file?

Comment: dcg I need to use process start to run the ENCODED vbscript file WITHOUT its .VBE extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to run an encoded VBScript file, you want the `VBScript.Encode` engine rather than the `VBScript` engine. Try using `//e:VBScript.Encode` as your first argument to `wscript`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is with the file not having an extension and you can rename it you could do something like:

```
string filename = ....
if (!Path.HasExtension(filename))
{
    string t = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, ".vbe");
    File.Move(filename, t);
    filename = t;
}

// rest of your code
```